# Vulkan API: moving rendering work into its own thread

Tags: vulkan

I'm learning the Khronos Vulkan API, and I'm having a hard time getting synchronization to work across multiple threads.

I'm trying to break the Rendering work into its own thread. My idea is to have a main thread, which will be in charged of high level app management stuff and, importantly, it will call VkQueuePresentKHR() to present the surface. However, the actual VkCmd* rendering work is to be done on a dedicated thread.

I want my app to use triple buffering, as it's very important for me to have a smooth 60fps. On a video presentation, NVIDIA mentioned that you'll want to have 1 VkCommandPool per framebuffer, and to just clear the entire pool after each use; that is more efficient than trying to clean individual Command Buffers. I'm going a step further: I'm trying to break up the rendering work into 6 Queues:

- 3 graphic queues: each frame gets its own dedicated queue.
- 1 for presentation.
- 1 for misc one time graphic commands.
- 1 for dedicated transfer work

My GTX770 video card has 16 general purpose queues + 1 dedicated transfer queue, so this should be no problem. Each queue would have its own VkCommandPool. The Queues, CommandPool, and CommandBuffer objects are created in the main thread, and then used in the Render thread.

[image]

I'm running into the following issues:

- VkAcquireNextImageKHR is called in the Render thread. If the thread acquires 3 images, then I can't just call the function again and rely on it to block until the next image is available. Instead, I get a validation layer error that I've grabbed all the images that are available. And, anyway, I would prefer to detect that no image is currently available, so that I can do other work in the thread, such as defragmenting memory. HOW CAN I TELL WHEN ALL THE IMAGES ARE CURRENTLY ACQUIRED, AND THAT I SHOULDN'T YET CALL vkAcquireNextImageKHR.
- How can I find out if vkQueuePresentKHR() is done presenting, and that I can send another frame to be presented? I don't know how to tell when I can start using that framebuffer again.
- It's not safe to clear the CommandPool right after  vkQueueSubmit() returns, correct? To clear a CommandPool, Do I need to monitor the fence that is given to vkQueueSubmit()? It's not entirely clear to me from reading the spec.
- I know it's not safe to mess with a CommandPool from multiple threads, but is it ok to work with multiple Queues/CommandPools from one thread?
- I might be doing something wrong, but it looks like after calling vkResetFence() on some fence, you can't call vkGetFenceStatus() on it, or you'll get a validation layer error. Is this correct?

Comment: That's a lot of questions, which is going to make this hard to answer. I suggest asking them (or only closely-related questions) separately, e.g. the vkAcquireNextImageKHR questions don't have much to do with the command pool questions.

Comment: This wasn't part of your question, but using a different queue for each frame isn't going to help you, and may hurt -- you want a particular task in frame N to be worked on before the same task in frame N+1, so using a single queue makes sense, and even with appropriate serialization to ensure that across multiple queues you're going to be paying scheduling / context-switch overhead.

Comment: Why would You acquire all the available swapchain images at once? There may be a reason to do that but in most cases this isn't necessary, or even may cause trouble.

Comment: @Dess: "*3 graphic queues: each frame gets its own dedicated queue.*" This is a terrible idea. Not every GPU even has multiple graphics queues. And the inter-queue synchronization requirements are rather substantial. You should only use multiple queues if you need asychronous execution of commands, and the synchronization between your queues proves that you *don't*.

Comment: @JesseHall, NicolBolas: Understood. More queues don't necessarily mean better throughput, and might actually hurt performance. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Ekzuzy: The code was on its own thread, and it was just looping and calling that function asynchronously. It was a bad idea, and I know that, now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` acquires ownership of an image, and `vkQueuePresentKHR` releases ownership of it back to the presentation engine. The PE needs to own the image it's currently displaying, and sometimes others. Acquire will block until an image becomes available or the timeout expires. You get the validation error when there is no way you can rely on Acquire to return, since you haven't presented enough images. The spec says:

   > Let *n* be the total number of images in the swapchain, *m* be the value of `VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::minImageCount`, and *a* be the number of presentable images that the application has currently acquired (i.e. images acquired with `vkAcquireNextImageKHR`, but not yet presented with `vkQueuePresentKHR`). `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` can always succeed if *a* ≤ *n* - *m* at the time `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` is called. `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` should not be called if *a* > *n* - *m* with a timeout of `UINT64_MAX`; in such a case, `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` may block indefinitely.
2. The semaphore/fence you pass in to `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` will signal when the PE is done reading from the image. At that point, you can start writing to it again, and present it when ready.
3. You can't clear the command pool as long as any of the command buffers in it are still executing. You know when they're done executing when the fence passed to `vkQueueSubmit` signals.
4. Yes, you can use any number of objects of any type from a single thread. Nothing in the Vulkan implementation is bound to a particular thread it's used on. The restrictions on accessing objects *concurrently* from multiple threads are similar to what you'd have for your own objects: some object are serialized internally so concurrent access is okay, other objects are not.
5. That seems wrong. You should be able to call `vkGetFenceStatus` on any valid fence at any time.

Comment: Thanks, man. I appreciate the answers to my compound question. I'll ask better questions in the future. I'm still ignorant about 1 portion of your answer: I don't get the 2 equations: a ≤ n - m , and a > n - m. Specifically, I don't understand what minImageCount has to do with it. Can you please explain that in english?

Comment: The variable 'm' stands for minImageCount. So a ≤ n - m means that if the swapchain has 3 images and minImageCount was 2, then you can have two images acquired (and not yet presented) at any given time. If you already have two acquired, and try to acquire a third (a > n-m), vkAcquireNextImageKHR will probably fail with VK_TIMEOUT. If you have an infinite timeout, it might never return because (a) the timeout won't ever be reached and (b) another image can't become available until you present one of the ones you already have.

Comment: a <= n - m  == 2 <= (3 - 2) == 2 <= 1. To me, that looks like you can only have 1 image at any one time (a == 1) . What I meant by the minImageCount is that I don't know why that's relevant as part of the equation. But, that's some implementation detail that I should just accept. The equation, thought, doesn't sound like you can have 2 images acquired at the same time when n = 3 and m = 2

Comment: Yes, sorry, 'a' is limited to one; acquiring the second with infinite timeout might block indefinitely. The minImageCount is indeed for implementation-specific details. For example, for most present modes an implementation might require double-buffering (minImageCount==2). Or if the window is on a remote or wireless display, the PE might actually be a video encoder that needs one or more frames of history in order to encode the current frame.